# prevent uitableview from cancelling touch events after a horizontal touch

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitouch

I have a UITableView. If you touch a row, and then slide your finger left or right, it seems to block any further UITouch events from being recognized.

I have 2 tableviews. I want to be able to slide a row from the right tableview to the left, and as I'm dragging I want to still be able to scroll around on the left tableview view to decide where to drop the row from the right tableview. But as soon as I drag the row to the left, no more touch events are recognized.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has some built in gesture recognition stuff that might be fighting with you.

Did you implement `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your data source? If so, its consuming your swipe gesture for the built in row-deletion stuff. See Apple's Documentation: [tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acommitEditingStyle%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a)